# Where are user manuals for ASP.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I've seen many items dealing with Mvc but I can't find actual documentation from Microsoft. If someone could point me at it, that would be great.

Comment: all you had to do was to use these magic words in google : `asp.net mvc tutorial` . Any how [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/getting-started)

Comment: Yes I've seen that and loads of other stuff but I have yet to find where/if Microsoft has produced documentation in the same way as IBM did for (say) Informix where it has a variety of publications beginning with a Quick Start Guide all the way to to an XML User's Guide - over 40 in total.

Answer (score 0):

This is the [link](http://www.asp.net/mvc) with the Microsoft ASP .NET MVC documentation.

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/default.aspx) documentation could be very helpful also when developing .NET stuff.